# PowerShell script to standalone executable

Tags: powershell, exe

I have a .ps1 file and I wanted to run the script when double-click! But a ps1 file is a script file so when you double click on in it opens a the notepad to edited.

So I what a way to execute the ps1 script!

I know that I can make a bat file and that execute the ps1 file and the problem with that is, that I need to files the .ps1 and a .bat! The problem that I'm facing is that there will be to files and so inconvenient...

So! Is there a way to make exe from a ps1 script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might try something like http://www.battoexeconverter.com/ You'll still need to create the bat file, but the two files(ps1 and bat) can be combined into a single .exe file for portability.

Answer (score 2):

Import this into the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell]
@="0"
```

or run this on the command line:

```
set "key=HKCU\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell"
reg add "%key%" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f
```

Both operations do the same: change the default action for PowerShell scripts to "Run with PowerShell" for the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

you might try PS2EXE http://ps2exe.codeplex.com/ (still beta though)

Comment: the .config is there a way to remove or not use it? the way i see it a  just a xml telling the framework it useing